# React with Ecmascript6 classes problems using Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'moving to React ES6 as the recommended way to write React classes. I'm starting from a simple example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

require('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
require('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dashboard/>,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

And my component in ES6:

```
import React from 'react';


class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, Don Trump</h1>
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on Chrome 55:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
    at invariant (VM1093 bundle.js:9069)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (VM1093 bundle.js:23166)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (VM1093 bundle.js:23589)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (VM1093 bundle.js:23480)
    at Object.mountComponent (VM1093 bundle.js:16018)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (VM1093 bundle.js:28717)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (VM1093 bundle.js:17017)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (VM1093 bundle.js:28739)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (VM1093 bundle.js:17017)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (VM1093 bundle.js:26233)
```

I thinks there is something simple I'm missing. Help appreacited.

Comment: you need to  add "export default" for the Dashboard  Component

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message might have it right:

> You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Export your `Dashboard` component like the following:

```
import React from 'react';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 5):

Add

> export default Dashboard

At the end of your component;
So the new code will be

> ```
> class Dashboard extends React.Component {
>   render() {
>     return <h1>Hello, Don Trump</h1>
>   }
> }
> export default Dashboard;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the class. You can actually export and declare at the same time

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
  }
}
```